# Node.js crypto generate lowercase keypair

Tags: node.js, cryptography, key, signature

Using the node.js crypto library, I would like to generate a lowercase keypair that I can use for signing data.

This code works, however the keys have uppercase characters too.
(The ---BEGIN PUBLIC KEY--- part doesnt matter only the body of the key)

```
const crypto = require('crypto');

const { privateKey, publicKey } = crypto.generateKeyPairSync('rsa', {
  namedCurve: 'sect239k1',
  modulusLength: 512,
  publicKeyEncoding: { type: 'spki', format: 'pem' },
  privateKeyEncoding: { type: 'pkcs8', format: 'pem' }
});
```

Comment: `console.log(publicKey.toLowerCase())` should print your publickey in lowercase

Comment: First of all, why do you need it lower case?

Comment: Actually I dont need it anymore

Comment: How can I delete this question?